# Глитч CSS spin coin анимации в браузере Safari

Tags: html, css, css3, safari

Когда анимация доходит до гурта (край монеты), в Safari анимацию потряхивает. Я пробовал включить вендорные префиксы -webkit везде, где только можно, но не помогло. Пробовал translateX заменить на translate3D, тряска в Сафари уменьшится, зато она появится и в Хроме.
Ещё пробовал делать анимацию через transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1), но там будто-то бы пропадает шаг, где должен быть отчетливо виден гурт

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

:root {
  /* --lowlight: #111; */
  --side: #c2e635;
  --side-dark: #6ed92d;
  --coin-size: 136px;
}
/*
  everything above is positioning and variables.
  this is where the real fun begins...
*/

.coin {
  height: var(--coin-size);
  width: var(--coin-size);
  margin: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  will-change: transform;
}

.coin::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: var(--coin-size);
  width: var(--coin-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;

  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  will-change: transform, width, box-shadow, background-color;
}

.coin.silver::before {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
  background-image: url("https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-icon-m/p/4dd9406e-96d3-11e6-aa77-00163ec9f5fa/3927985343/java-development-kit-64-java-43-569305.png");
}

/* animation definitions */

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    width: var(--coin-size);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 var(--side-dark);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  49.999% {
    width: 0.1rem;
    box-shadow: 0.05rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.1rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.15rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.2rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.25rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.3rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.35rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.4rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.45rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.5rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.55rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.6rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.65rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.7rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.75rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.8rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.85rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.9rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.95rem 0 0 var(--side), 1rem 0 0 var(--side),
      1.05rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.1rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.15rem 0 0 var(--side),
      1.2rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.25rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.3rem 0 0 var(--side),
      1.35rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.4rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.45rem 0 0 var(--side),
      1.5rem 0 0 var(--side);
    transform: translateX(-14px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-14px);
    background-color: var(--lowlight);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

  50.001% {
    width: 0.1rem;
    box-shadow: -0.05rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.1rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.15rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.2rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.25rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.3rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.35rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.4rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.45rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.5rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.55rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.6rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.65rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.7rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.75rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.8rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.85rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.9rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.95rem 0 0 var(--side), -1rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.05rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -1.1rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.15rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.2rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -1.25rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.3rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -1.35rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.4rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -1.45rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.5rem 0 0 var(--side);
    transform: translateX(14px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(14px);
    background-color: var(--lowlight);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }

  100% {
    width: var(--coin-size);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 var(--side-dark);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
  <div class="coin silver"></div>
  <div class="coin silver"></div>
  <div class="coin silver"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то делал что-то похожее. [Вот результат](https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/oQzbgw) Возможно потому-то вы не используете `transform-style: preserve-3d;`

```
.coin {
  font-size: $size;
  width: $width;
  height: 1em;
  background: $inner-color;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: rotate $speed infinite linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.coin .side,
.coin:before,
.coin:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: $color;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: -0.396em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  color: $color;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 0 #7a0413, -1px -2px 0 #460416;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.coin .tails,
.coin:after {
  left: -0.396em;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.coin:before,
.coin:after {
  background: $inner-color;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.coin:after {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}
.imageCoin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1em;
  background-color: $color;
  //object-fit: cover;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```